# How much do other CDNs charge?

Tags: cdn, pricing

I'm currently using Amazon S3 and CloudFront as a CDN to serve my images. Amazon publish [their prices](http://aws.amazon.com/cloudfront/#pricing) on the site: $0.120 per GB transfer and $0.0075 per 10,000 HTTP Requests.

However, other CDNs don't seem to list any prices at all. In particular I'm looking at EdgeCast and NetDNS - does anyone know their typical prices? What about other services?

Comment: Good question, but surely one that deserves to be a community post? I'd envision a table of costs?

Comment: @Mike: do we have Community Wiki anymore? It's not showing up on the question edit (nor if I click "Ask Question"). Anyone can submit edits now, so we can still have one solid canonical answer that anyone can contribute to.

Comment: @DisgruntledGoat [See here](http://meta.webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/543/button-to-make-a-question-community-wiki) for what happened to the wiki button. You can flag and request if you really want it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not sure what you're having trouble finding. Pricing is easily available on the internet for many CDN providers (basically all except LimeLight and Level3). Some examples:

- Rackspace Cloud files (using Akamai's huge CDN) is US$0.18/GB
- MaxCDN (the pay-as-you-go version of NetDNA) starts at US$0.10/GB
- Voxel VoxCAST starts at US$0.10/GB
- CacheFly starts at US$0.39/GB
- GoGrid (which uses EdgeCast) starts at $0.25/GB

You get volume discounts, and depending on provider can better pricing if you are willing to commit to certain spending under a contract-based service.

Obviously there is more to it than just price. Stability is paramount. Many of these CDNs are architected quite differently, have different features, and offer different performance levels for different regions and use cases. For example, the anycast-based CDNs (such as CacheFly and MaxCDN) typically offer the lowest latency, and are great if your customers are in secure environments that must white-list external providers by IP address. But those same providers also seem to have fewer network nodes and peering points than CDNs that use DNS-based redirection.

See [CloudHarmony](http://cloudharmony.com/clouds_cdn) for a more complete list of CDN providers.